# string to array in the same order PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have string list of data like so :

```
Category(1,2,"some text");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
Category(1,2,"some text");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
```

I need to convert this to array in same order, some thing like this for example :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
   (
       ['category'] => Category(1,2,"some text")
       ['posts'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [1] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [2] => post(111,233,"post")
                )
   )
[2] => Array
   (
       ['category'] => Category(1,2,"some text")
       ['posts'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [1] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [2] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [3] => post(111,233,"post")
                    [4] => post(111,233,"post")
                )
   )
)
```

I could get the Categories array alone and posts array alone, but how can I put them together in one array in the same order ..

```
preg_match_all("/(category)\(+(.*?)\)/",$string,$cats , PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all("/(post)\(+(.*?)\)/",$string,$posts , PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($cats);
print_r($posts);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tokenize the string and then parse each item one by one, like this:

```
$result = array();
$token_list = explode(";\n",$string);
$category_counter = -1;//index trick for the first occorrence of Category

foreach($token_list as $token){
  if(substr($token,0,8) == "Category"){
    $category_counter++;
    $result[$category_counter]["category"] = $token;
  }else{
    $result[$category_counter]["posts"][] = $token;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Giovanni, almost there, I think the only issue is, I can't get substr($token,0,1) right, it doesn't return "Category", when I tried it manually, it returned "1" !.. I'm trying to figure it out what the issue is, thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, it does retuned "category" but the condition never work, I got an array like : 
Category array 
(
[-1] => Array
   (
       [post] => Array
           (
           [0] => Category(1,2,"some text")
           [1] => post(111,233,"post")
           [2] => post(111,233,"post")
           [3] => Category(1,2,"some text")
           [4] => post(111,233,"post")
           [5] => post(111,233,"post")
           [6] => post(111,233,"post")

Comment: Is your string like this, I mean with the same case-sensitivenes and new lines after the semicolons?
`
$string = 'Category(1,2,"some text");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
Category(1,2,"some text");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");
post(111,233,"post");';
`

Comment: I got strange error, when I echo $token, I got list of "category ...", but when I echo substr($token,0,8), I got nothing.. I think I have issue with the string itself coz it's a huge list of data.. I'm gonna check them and get back here.. Thanks a lot Giovanni for the help and your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome! it worked now, I had an issue with my string, I increased the number of letters in substr function and used strpos() to check if the string line contains "Category" if( strpos(substr($token,0,15), 'Category') !== false) .. and everything works now! Thanks a lot Giovanni!